# Video call and share writing

Tags: ipad, facetime, handwriting

This summer, I will be having meetings with my Ph.D. advisor, and since he's traveling, we'll be meeting via Skype or FaceTime. Since we are working on mathematics, we need a way to see each other's writing, so we can quickly suggest ideas to each other and talk about them.

He will be using a MacBook Pro 2017 and I'll be using my iMac 2018 or MacBook Pro 2017.
I have an iPad pro with Apple Pencil; I'm not sure if he does. I mention this because it may be a solution that we have separate writing apps open on our iPads even as we FaceTime. In case he doesn't have an iPad already, he will of course need to get some device that has the ability to receive handwriting.

What is the best solution? Including what gear he'd need to have.

This would also be a great question for online tutoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[AWW App](https://awwapp.com/)**

From a simple Google Search (and some testing) I have found a WebApp that allows real time collaboration on a whiteboard. From my tests the board is updated once the mouse is released.

It works in realtime on Mac's and iOS devices meaning you and your Ph.D. advisor could use it at the same time no matter what device you guys are on.

You can...

- Draw with different colors
- Type text
- Add Shapes
- Create Post-it notes
- Add Pages
- Export your board as a PDF or Image
- Save your board for future use
- **Add collaborators**

Extra premium features are available.

**Note:** I am in no way affiliated with this company or product and will not be impacted by the purchasing (or not) of this product

Comment: UPDATE Nov 2023: AWW app has merged with miro.com boards. There are functinos to share anonymous acountless boards through https://webwhiteboard.com/